# Call a function in a .bat file from within another .bat in Windows Command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to call a function e.g. :dosomething which in my 1.bat file. the function exists in 2.bat file. How can I call it there ?

Comment: You're going to have to modify 2.bat. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes,totally !  I just can't to seem to find how to call the specific function from outside !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with calling a function stub inside 1.bat and then invoking 2.bat without call

```
:: 1.bat
@Echo off
Echo This is 1.bat
Call :dosomething args
Echo back in 1.bat
pause
Exit /b
:dosomething
Echo Sub %0 in 1.bat
2.bat %*
```

---

```
:: 2.bat
@goto :Eof
:dosomething
Echo this is 2.bat %*
```

Sample run:

```
This is 1.bat
Sub :dosomething in 1.bat
this is 2.bat args
back in 1.bat
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thanks ! this works nicely !

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach here would be, in `1.bat`

```
call 2.bat something realparameterlist
```

and 2.bat is structured:

```
@echo off
shift&goto %1

:something
(whatever)
goto :eof
```

Of course, this could be made smarter:

```
@echo off
set "junkvar=%1"
if "%junkvar:~0,1%"==":" shift&goto %1
:: processing if first arg doesn't begin ':'

:something
(whatever)
goto :eof
```

where the first argument supplied must begin `:`

It should be noted that `%*` will still contain the `[:]routinename` regardless of whether the simpler or more complex approach is taken.